# USe SurfaceView to stop screenshot?

Tags: android, screenshot

Do you guys think there is anyway to to stop screenshot using SurfaceView..like providing a fake surface for screenshot

Comment: Sorry! Could you add further information?

Comment: Well i want prevent screenshot to be taken..i used flag_secure but it is disabled by the virtualexpose app..making the content exposed for srceenshot

Comment: Add some more information, so people understand you and you get help as soon as possible

Comment: @ChaitanyaAgarwal do as `Sana'a Al-ahdal` said

Comment: but @Istiak..this code is getting disabled by 3rd party app like virtualExpose

Answer (score 0):

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```